# Are lambda expressions right-valued? Or is it the left value?

Tags: c++, lambda

I want to keep the lambda inside a class and it is passed the lambda through the constructor. At this time, I am confused about how to declare the constructor correctly.

```
using CallbackType = std::function<void()>;

class Job
{
private:
    CallbackType callback_;

public:
    // 1
    Job(CallbackType&& callback) : callback_(std::move(callback)) {}

    // 2
    Job(CallbackType callback) : callback_(callback) {}

    // 3
    Job(CallbackType& callback) : callback_(callback) {}
};
```

I would be grateful if you could explain which of the above constructors is preferable and why.

In particular, constructor number 2 works correctly, and I am also curious about the reason.

Comment: I usually use number 4) `template<typename fn_t> Job(fn_t&& callback) : callback_{callback})`, so any function/functor type can be passed as temporary.  Option 2 will always make a (cheap) copy.  So it is actually the one I would not use.

Comment: 2) might also have `std::move`.

Comment: 3) won't work from r-value (as lambda).

Comment: Note that lambda is **not** `std::function`, but might be convertible to.

Comment: How do you construct a Job?  `Job job([]{ std::cout << "Hello world\n"; });` will construct a temporary **CallbackType** (which is a `std::function<void()>`) from the lambda.

Answer (score 3):

Do this: `Job(CallbackType callback) : callback_(std::move(callback)) {}`.

This is a good option in general for consturctors accepting member values, no matter what value category will be passed to them.

It's possible to be slightly more optimal, at the cost of having to write more code, and I wouldn't bother with this by default (either two overloads: `const T &` and `T &&`, or a single template constructor with perfect forwarding).

A lambda is an rvalue (a prvalue, more specifically) (you can test it by doing `decltype(( []{} ))` and observing that the resulting type is not a reference; an xvalue would result in `&&` and an lvalue would result in `&`), but this doesn't matter because a lambda is not `std::function`. A temporary `std::function` will be constructed from the lambda. But since the user can provide an lvalue `std::function` too, this doesn't really affect how you should write the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You could make your constructor accept any `void` invokable that doesn't require any parameters and then use perfect forwarding to store it in `callback_`:

```cpp
#include <type_traits> // is_invocable_r_v
#include <utility>     // forward

//...

template <class Func>
    requires std::is_invocable_r_v<void, Func>
Job(Func&& callback) : callback_(std::forward<Func>(callback)) {}
```

`Func` is here a forwarding reference (an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter), which makes [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) useful. It'll forward lvalues as either lvalues or as rvalues, depending on `Func`, so that the original value category of the argument you passed to `Job` is preseved when passed to the constructor of the `std::function<void()>`.